# 「閉じる」よりも「クローズする」の方がよい

Tags: 討議, 翻訳, 日本語

質問を投稿すると、「共有 編集 閉じる」のようなメニューが表示されますが、「閉じる」をクリックすると「この質問をクローズすべき理由は何ですか？」という画面が表示されます。

「閉じる」と「クローズする」と用語が揺れているので「クローズする」に統一した方がいいと思います。

そもそも「閉じる」という言葉は「画面を閉じる」のように、気軽に実施できる操作を想像してしまいます。

なので、重大なアクションであることをイメージできる用語の方がいいと思います。
（そういう意味では「クローズする」できれば「質問をクローズする」ぐらい書いた方が想像しやすいですが）

Comment: 「閉じる」だと軽すぎるというのはよくわかるので「閉鎖」はどうでしょう？

Answer (score 3):

クローズされた後のスレッドタイトルに`[クローズ済み]`と表記されるので、
文言を統一するのであれば"クローズする"が良いかと思います。

"クローズ"と言う文言はスレッドの状態の**closed**から来ているかと思いますが
「スレッドを`closed`の状態にする」と言う意味合いでも"クローズする"の方が分かりやすいかと思います。

ただ、世間一般的に"クローズ"が"閉じる"と言った意味合い持つことを知らない人は小数かと思います。
`閉じる`を`クローズする`に変更するのは賛成ですが、
それにより意味合いが重くなるか？という点に関しては疑問を感じます。

Comment: 日本語の性質上、ほぼ同一の意味をもつにも関わらずあえて英単語表記にすることで違った意味合いを相手に意識させることが少なからずあると思います。
ブラウザ上で`閉じる`とだけ書いてある場合、UIデザインにもよるでしょうが、初見の場合大抵が**ページやメニュー等を閉じる**という意味合いを真っ先に思い浮かべると思います。そういった意味では、`クローズする`と書いてあれば、ページを閉じるという意味でとる人は少ないのではないでしょうか？
意味合いの重みというよりは、**操作対象の違いを意識させる**という方向性で捉えるのはいかがでしょうか。