# 「閉じる/クローズ」を別の言葉で言い換える

Tags: 討議

ここ最近の討議に関連してネットを検索していたところ、以下の記事を見つけました。話の対象は英語版ですが、日本語版がリリースされた後の話のようです。

**[Stack Overflowが開発者向けイベント「Dev Days」を開催](https://thinkit.co.jp/story/2015/10/22/6345)**

> 一般人がそのルールにびっくりしないようにする必要があるともSpolsky氏は述べた。
>
> たとえば、「適切な言葉を探すのは大変」として、Stack Overflowで望ましくない質問に対して
>
> - 「Closed（閉鎖された）」
> - 「Too Localized（範囲が狭すぎる）」
> - 「Not Constructive（非建設的な質問）」
> - 「Not a Real Question（本当に質問ではない）」
>
> という言葉を使っていたところ、やる気のあるユーザーが離れてしまったと語った。そして、それぞれ
>
> - 「On hold（改善待ち）」
> - 「Off topic（トピックから外れています）」
> - 「Primarily opinion-based（主観的な回答しか集まらない）」
> - 「Unclear what you're asking（質問内容がはっきりしない）」
>
> と言いかえたところ、編集率が約2倍にアップしたと報告した。

「クローズ」だとそこで質問を打ち切ってしまう印象だから、「改善待ち」にしたという事のようです。

日本語版でも票が一定数入れられると「改善待ち」表記にはなりますが、票を入れる段階では「閉じる」や「クローズ」という表現が混在している状況ですし、メタ内でも「クローズ」という表現を使われている方が多い印象です。

そして「クローズ」という表現を使っているが故に、(レビューシステムに対して)必要以上にマイナスの印象を持ってしまっている気がします。

---

票を入れるのは(一定以上の信用度こそ必要なものの)質問者と対等な立場の一ユーザです。特権を振りかざして質問を跳ね返してるわけではないはずです。
票を集める程度には複数人が質問文に対して**疑問**を持って「もう少し詳しく書いてください」とお願いをするのは厳しい対応ですか？

システムの仕組み上すべての置き換えが難しいとしても、なるべく「閉じる/クローズ」という表現ではなく「改善待ち」など別の言葉で表示したり、利用するユーザ自身も意識付けする必要があるのかなと思いました。

Comment: "Not a Real Question" の "Real Question" はブログ記事 ["Real Questions Have Answers"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/) を汲んだ言い方です。和訳するとしたら「現実的な質問」あたりでしょうか……。どういう意味かはこちらの Meta.SE の投稿にまとまっています： https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145677/341401

Comment: 一応、クローズという言葉は削除されたわけではありません。最初は「改善待ち」状態になりますが、それから 5 日の間に再オープンされない場合は「クローズ済み」という表現に変わります (これは本家 Stack Overflow も同様です。参考： [クローズに関するヘルプページ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions))。　／　このこととは別に、「クローズ」を全て「改善待ち」に変えようというお話でしたら、面白いご提案だと思います :)

Comment: 「改善待ち」の猶予期間を経て、最終的には「クローズ」となるわけですね。そこは見落としていました。

Answer (score 1):

僕もクローズという言葉には戸惑った記憶があります。
長ったらしいのでもう少し短い言葉にした方がいいかとは思いますが、
たたき台として、「改善待ち期間を過ぎたため、一時的に回答できない状態である」という趣旨を
より解りやすく簡潔にした日本語に置き換えられるといいですね。

もしかするとですが、「質問内容がはっきりしない」も「質問の焦点がはっきりしない」に
したほうがどう改善すればいいのか、わかりやすくなるかも知れないと思いました。

同様にトピックという言葉もスタックオーバーフローでのジャーゴンと化していて、
概念としてはみんな把握しているけど、具体的な解釈は参加者毎に違ったりするのかなぁ。
これも日本語にならないかなぁと思いました。

ぼんやりとしたというか、それこそ「焦点がはっきりしない」回答になってしまったので
「いやいや、そう言うことじゃないって」って場合は遠慮無くマイナス投票して下さい

Comment: +1: スタック・オーバーフローの専門用語は昔英語から翻訳するときに https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11/19110 などのメタ投稿を通して決めたという経緯があります。特にクローズに関しては「閉じる」から「クローズする」に変えたようです: https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299/19110 。もっと分かりやすい表現があれば、変えた方が初心者の方々にやさしいと思います。